# Bootstrap grid layout on top of a background with padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please excuse me for butchering all of the terms here, but I am going to try to get across what I hope to accomplish. Right now I have managed to create a background image that scales to the window size and a navigation bar. I would like to start adding some bootstrap grid items on top of all this, but also under the navigation bar. Here is my 3-year-old depiction of what I am trying to make:

[image]

As of right now, I have called the background image class and then the navigation class. I am now trying to add a container so that I can use a bootstrap grid of some sort to add the four buttons and a panel.

The issues I am running into are that it seems blank rows will 0 in height and not create the buffer from the top. Another issue i have is the layering. My bootstrap grid items appear behind my background.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for layout? Am I doing this all wrong and should be using something else entirely? I am really trying to keep all of this to a single index.html file and avoid importing unneeded assets or running a bunch of scripts.

Here is the code I am working with right now:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: .80;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}
.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("img/home_bg.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #111;
}
/* Add a dark background color with a little bit see-through */ 
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #2d2d30;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    opacity:0.8;
}

/* Add a gray color to all navbar links */
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand { 
    color: #d5d5d5 !important;
}

/* On hover, the links will turn white */
.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* The active link */
.navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color:#29292c !important;
}

/* Remove border color from the collapsible button */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
}

/* Dropdown */
.open .dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff ;
    background-color: #555 !important;
}

/* Dropdown links */
.dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #000 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu form div {
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

/* On hover, the dropdown links will turn red */
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: red !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="bgimg-1"></div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="myhomepage">title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">WELCOME, <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="registration/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">REGISTER<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <form action="registration/register.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="reg_username" id="reg_username" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="reg_email" id="reg_email" class="form-control" placeholder=" Email Address" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="reg_password_1" id="reg_password_1" class="form-control" placeholder=" Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="reg_password_2" id="reg_password_2" class="form-control" placeholder=" Confirm Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value=" Register Now">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">LOGIN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <form action="registration/register.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="log_username" id="log_username" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="log_password" id="log_password" class="form-control" placeholder=" Password">
                        </div>
                        <!--
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value=" Login Now">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">test1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">test2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">test3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:yellow;">test4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after messing around with this a bit I figured out that you can just stack containers and then make the highest level container have an image in the style section. I am not sure if this is the proper approach, but it seems to be putting the bootstrap containers on top of the background. The only issues I see are the lack of padding at the moment and now my navigation bar dropdowns now display behind the container buttons. That being said, I wanted to at least get this up here in case anyone can fill in the blanks.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
            color: #777;
            }
            .caption {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 50%;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            }
            .caption span.border {
            background-color: #111;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 18px;
            font-size: 25px;
            letter-spacing: 10px;
            }
            h3 {
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
            color: #111;
            }
            /* Add a dark background color with a little bit see-through */ 
            .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #2d2d30;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 11px !important;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            opacity:0.8;
            }
            /* Add a gray color to all navbar links */
            .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand { 
            color: #d5d5d5 !important;
            }
            /* On hover, the links will turn white */
            .navbar-nav li a:hover {
            color: #fff !important;
            }
            /* The active link */
            .navbar-nav li.active a {
            color: #fff !important;
            background-color:#29292c !important;
            }
            /* Remove border color from the collapsible button */
            .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
            border-color: transparent;
            }
            /* Dropdown */
            .open .dropdown-toggle {
            color: #fff ;
            background-color: #555 !important;
            }
            /* Dropdown links */
            .dropdown-menu li a {
            color: #000 !important;
            }
            .dropdown-menu form div {
            padding: 0px 20px;
            }
            /* On hover, the dropdown links will turn red */
            .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
            background-color: red !important;
            }
            .button, .tablinks {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #2d2d30;
            color: #d5d5d5;
            border: none;
            outline:none;
            font-size: 11px !important;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            opacity:0.8;
            }
            .active, .button:hover, .tablinks:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #555 !important;
            }
            .container-bg {
            position: relative;
            opacity: .80;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-image: url("img/home_bg.jpg");
            height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-bg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="myhomepage">title</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">WELCOME, <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="registration/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">REGISTER<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <form action="registration/register.php" method="post">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" name="reg_username" id="reg_username" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="email" name="reg_email" id="reg_email" class="form-control" placeholder=" Email Address" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" name="reg_password_1" id="reg_password_1" class="form-control" placeholder=" Password">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" name="reg_password_2" id="reg_password_2" class="form-control" placeholder=" Confirm Password">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value=" Register Now">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">LOGIN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <form action="registration/register.php" method="post">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" name="log_username" id="log_username" class="form-control" placeholder=" Username" value="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" name="log_password" id="log_password" class="form-control" placeholder=" Password">
                                            </div>
                                            <!--
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>
                                                              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                                                          </label>
                                                      </div>
                                                  -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value=" Login Now">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!-- Tab links -->
                <div class="tab" id="tab">
                  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab1')"  id="defaultOpen">tab1</button>
                  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
                  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab3')">tab3</button>
                  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab4')">tab4</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <!-- Tab content -->
                            <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
                              <h3>tab1</h3>
                              <p>list stuff for tab1</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
                              <h3>tab2</h3>
                              <p>list stuff for tab2</p> 
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
                              <h3>tab3</h3>
                              <p>list stuff for tab3</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tab4" class="tabcontent">
                              <h3>tab4</h3>
                              <p>list stuff for tab4</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            // Declare all variables
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

            // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }

            // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```